# Performing Multiple Segues with UIActionSheetDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I'm looking to have multiple segues through a single `UIBarButtonItem` button, and depending on the response through the `UIActionSheetDelegate`, the correct `UIViewController` would load through a `push` segue. This is my current code in for the `UIActionSheetDelegate`.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // rate this app
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"bugReportSegue" sender:self];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"featureRequestSegue" sender:self];
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that I cannot link the same button to multiple views through Storyboard segues. I'm wondering if there's a workaround.

**EDIT**

This is what my code looks like now: (minus the Storyboard)

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // rate this app
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bugReportIdentifier"];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"featureRequestIdentifier"];
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a segue, just have the View Controller in the Storyboard disconnected and assign it a Storyboard Identifier. Then you can instantiate an instance of it using `self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` within each of your functions

Comment: @JackWu How would I go about doing that?

Comment: let me draft up an answer for you :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `segue` with `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Consider using the `StoryboardID` along with `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:`

To do so, in the Storyboard, simply create a view controller and don't connect any segues to it. In the third tab in the properties inspector, assign it a `Storyboard ID`:

[image: Example]

Then, in your code, you can create an instance like this:

`[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePicker"]`

This will create a new instance every time though, so you should still save it and re-use it whenever possible.

**EDIT**: After you get the view controller, you need to present it yourself.

If you are using a `NavigationViewController` call:

```
UIViewController * newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePicker"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController];
```

If not you can use:

```
UIViewController * newController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ImagePicker"];
[self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Edit 2**:
Here is what your final code should look like:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // rate this app
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        UIViewController * controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bugReportIdentifier"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    else if (buttonIndex == 2)
    {
        UIViewController * controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bugReportIdentifier"];
        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this, and it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not getting any errors in the command line, which I guess is a good thing, but when I click the `UIActionSheet` detail button, nothing happens where it's assigned to execute. I tested to make sure it was ever reaching the code with `NSLog`, and it was. Definitely doing something wrong on my part.

Comment: Okay I'm sorry...missed out on something. When you instantiate it, you just get the view controller. So you need to present it yourself using `presentViewController:` or `pushViewController`

Comment: As such? `[self presentViewController:BugReportViewController animated:YES completion:nil];` Because when I execute this I get an error on the `BugReportViewController` because it was expecting an expression.

Comment: Ah, okay. Let me try it out.

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't clear enough :p, you get a view controller back from the first call that you should pass to the second

Comment: If I'm not using a `NavigationViewController`, and I utilized the code shown above. There would be no point in utilizing the previous statement of `[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"bugReportIdentifier"];` Yes? It would simply be replaced by those two lines?